# How to insert layout meta info into all files matching a file pattern?

Tags: handlebars.js, metalsmith

I have lots of markdown source files, which are automatically generated by some data export step.

I'm using metalsmith-layouts and have e.g. these lines on top of my handcrafted (not automatically generated) markdown files in order to layout them using my layout.html:

```
---
layout: layout.html
title:  Downloads
---
```

How can I add the layout info dynamically to all files that match for example a file pattern tutorials/*.md, so that those files are also rendered with my layout? Adding this info to the files before conversion wouldn't be elegant.

Comment: have you found a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out meanwhile. It's possible to define a default layout to a file pattern this way:

```
// Apply the default layout to all .html files
.use(layouts({
    engine: 'handlebars',
    default: 'layout.html',
    directory: 'layouts',
    pattern: '**/*.html'
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

I very recently just wrote my first few Metalsmith plugins, one of which, [keymaster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/metalsmith-keymaster), can do exactly what you originally wanted.  To set the layout info to "foobar.html" for all the tutorials/*.md files, you would

```
use(keymaster(function() { return "foobar.html; },   // set it to "foobar.html"
              "layout",                              // in the layout field
              /tutorials.*md/);                      // for files matching this regex
```

(Note: my Regex isn't perfect, so that final line may be off.

Hmm, the fact that the first line is so clunky has me thinking of changin my API a bit.

Note, API has recently *slightly* changed, please read the docs.